# CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake

Tags: linux, ssl, nagios, nrpe, nagiosxi

I have NRPE daemon process running under xinetd on amazon ec2 instance and nagios server on my local machine.

The `check_nrpe -H [amazon public IP]` gives this error:

```
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
```

Both Nrpe are same versions. Both are compiled with this option:

```
./configure  --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

"allowed host" entry contains my local IP address.

What could be the possible reason of this error now??

Comment: Are you sure you don't reach your Amazon server with a public ip ? As far as Amazon server is in the Cloud i think you go through the Internet to query it. You should try to add your public ip address in "allowed host" list

Comment: I have added the public IP address of my machine in the 'allowed host' category. But the error remains. Nagios server is running on my local IP address(172.*.*.*) and not on public IP address(121.*.*.*)(sorry if saying this is doesn't make sense, I am new to all this). i.e. 

this works -----> 172.*.*.*/nagios

but not this ---> 121.*.*.*/nagios

Comment: one more point: when I run the command "check_nrpe -H (my amazon public IP)" from my amazon system, it still shows the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if you have access to it at all attempt a simple telnet on the address:port, a ping or traceroute to see where it is blocking.

```
telnet IP port
ping IP
traceroute -p $port IP
```

Also check on the target server that the nrpe daemon is working properly.

```
netstat -at | grep nrpe
```

You also need to check the versions of OpenSSL installed on both servers, as I have seen this break checks on occasion with the SSL handshake!

Answer (score 11):

If you are running nrpe as a service, make sure you have this line in your nrpe.cfg on the client side:

```
# example 192. IP, yours will probably differ
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.100
```

You say that is done, however, if you are running nrpe under xinetd, make sure to edit the `only_from` directive in the file `/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe`.

Don't forget to restart the xinetd service:

```
service xinetd restart
```

Answer (score 2):

check your `/var/sys/system.log` . In my case, it turned out my monitored IP was set to something else than the one I set in nrpe.cfg file. I don't know the cause of this change, though.

Comment: This solved my problem. In the syslog (in /var/log/syslog under Ubuntu), I saw that the connection was being refused on an IPv6 address, and not an IPv4 as I assumed. I added in the IPv6 address it said was being rejected to my nrpe.cf file and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

@jgritty was right.
you should edit `nrpe.cfg` and `nrpe` config files to allow your master nagios server's access:

```
vim /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cf
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,172.16.16.150
```

and

```
vim /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe
only_from= 127.0.0.1 172.16.16.150
```

Comment: Edit nrpe.cfg on the monitored machine. Add monitoring nagios/nrpe server's IP in `allowed_hosts` line. If you're using VM, you'll have to add hosting machine which where VM is running on.

Answer (score 2):

So many answers, none of them hit the reason why I ran into this issue.

It turns out that nagios has terrible cross-version support and this was caused by me having a version 2 "client" (machine being monitored) and a version 3 "server" (monitoring machine).

Once I upgraded the client to version 3, the problem went away and I could do a `check_nrpe -H [client IP]` without issues.

Note that I am not sure if client/server are the right terms with nagios, as in the case of an NRPE call, the server is really the machine being called, but I digress.

Comment: that was the solution to my problem also but in my case i had two clients with different versions accessing old nrpe server. so i additionally installed old check_nrpe version to new client. you have to copy files 'check_nrpe', 'libssl.so.0.9.8' and 'libcrypto.so.0.9.8'.

Answer (score 1):

That's somewhat of a catch-all error message for NRPE. Check your firewall rules and make sure that port is open. Also try disabling SELinux and seeing if that lets the connection through. It's likely not an SSL issue, but just an issue with the connection being refused.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running your Nagios server in a virtual machine on a host-only network. If this is so, this would stop any external access. Ensure that you have a NAT or Bridged Network available.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have restarted the Nagios Client Plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running nrpe using the xinetd service.

Make sure also (in addition to the above basic steps) that your nagios user is authenticating properly.  In my case:

```
Jun  6 15:05:52 gse2 xinetd[33237]: **Unknown user: nagios**<br>[file=/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe] [line=9]
Jun  6 15:05:52 gse2 xinetd[33237]: Error parsing attribute user - DISABLING
SERVICE [file=/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe] [line=9]
Jun  6 15:05:52 gse2 xinetd[33237]: **Unknown group: nagios**<br>[file=/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe] [line=10]
Jun  6 15:05:52 gse2 xinetd[33237]: Error parsing attribute group - DISABLING
SERVICE [file=/etc/xinetd.d/nrpe] [line=10]
Jun  6 15:05:52 gse2 xinetd[33237]: Service nrpe missing attribute user - DISABLING
```

Was showing in the /var/log messages.
It escaped me at first, but then I did a check on ypbind service and found it was not started.
After starting ypbind, nagios user and group was authenticating properly, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

some edge cases restarting `nagios-nrpe-server` doesn't help, due to the fact that process was not killed or it was not properly restarted.

just kill it manually then, and start.

Answer (score 0):

SSL handshake error msg.Beside the allow_host you should assign.

your nagios server is in a local lan with C type ip address such as 192.168.xxxx

when the target monitored server feedback the ssl msg to your local nagios server,the message should first comes to your public IP of your line,the message cannot across the public IP into your nagios server which ip is an internal one.

you need NAT to guide the SSL message from target server to inner nagios server.

Or you better use "GET" method which just get monitor message from the nagios client side,such as SNMP to fulfill the remote monitor of local resource of linux servers.

SSL need feedback in double direction.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

For me setting the following in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg on Client worked:

```
dont_blame_nrpe=1
```

It's and ubuntu 16.04 machine.
For other possible problems, I recommend looking at nrpe logs. Here is good article for configuring logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Debian 9 then there is [a known issue](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe/issues/113) regarding this problem, caused by OpenSSL dropping support for the method NRPE uses to initiate anonymous SSL connections.

The issue [seems to be fixed](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe/issues/113#issuecomment-311052948) but the fix hasn't made it into the official packages, yet.

Currently there seems to be no secure work-around.

Answer (score 0):

check configuration in /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe and verify the server IP. If it is showing only_from = 127.0.0.1 change it with Server IP .

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem had nothing to do with either of the configuration files (neither **xinetd** nor **nrpe.cfg**) - the problem has already been solved but one might find this solution helpful.

I had two clients (check_nrpe) - v4.X on a new Nagios server, v2.X on an old one - the old client was working fine with an old xinetd-based nrpe daemon running on Server X. The new client (v4.X) generated the SSL error while trying to communicate with Server X - what I did was the following:

1. I copied the old check_nrpe (v2.X) from the old Nagios server to **<nagios_dir>/libexec/check_nrpe_legacy** on the new Nagios server
2. I had access to all the *.so **libraries** the old check_nrpe used so I copied them as well and put into **/lib64** on the new Nagios server (*remember to use proper **symbolic links** - only putting libs into **/lib64** would not be enough; use **ldd ./check_nrpe** to find what links you need*)
3. I updated ldconfig cache (execute **ldconfig** command, no parameters)
4. I once again verified via **ldd ./check_nrpe** if I had all the libraries required for the older client to run on the new server
5. I defined a new command check_nrpe_legacy:

```html
define command {
            command_name    check_nrpe_legacy
            command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe_legacy/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

This is how I moved the old client onto the new server and made it work. The problem was gone.